# Camera: How to get image brightness while taking a picture?

Tags: android, camera, live, mode

I am making an application where the user has to be suggested about the quality of the picture he is about to take.
Like `"Brightness is low"` and `"Your environment is dim"`.

To achieve this, we need to put an overlay message on the camera preview while the user is viewing the subject.

Does anyone have an idea on how could we take the image brightness from the camera preview by using sensors or some other way in live mode even before the picture is taken?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the camera parameters as pointed out by @appleskin, would either of these methods help? `setWhiteBalance()` or `setExposureCompensation()`.If you want to achieve this functionality at run time then use native NDK effect for brightness.you can easily got **.so** files from github just use according to your further requirement.